# Failed download and duplicate GET issued by browser automatically

Tags: javascript, android, html, ajax, event-propagation

The ajax GET code below works fine on Chrome desktop browser and Firefox/Opera browsers on Android. But on Android Chrome browswer, when the Tomcat Java Servlet responds with a file down load, the DL fails, and the browser seems to be issuing a second GET automatically, my Server code downloads again, and it succeeds. This happens consistently with Android Chrome. (There is no nesting of GETs in client for it to really go up the DOM stack etc.). Like I said DL works on first GET in other mobile browsers. Any nsights please. Thanks in advance.

```
HTML

<form action="Tokens" method="GET" id="TokenSubmit" >
<input  type="text" name="BToken" id="tokenboxid">
</form>

JAVASCRIPT 

$('#TokenSubmit').on('submit', function(e) {
    cancelBubble(e);
    var tmpurl="/Strap/Tokens?BToken=" + $("#tokenboxid").val();
    $.ajax({url: tmpurl});
    e.preventDefault();
    SetName();
    return ;
}

function cancelBubble(e) {
  var evt = e ? e:window.event;
  if (evt.stopPropagation)    evt.stopPropagation();
  if (evt.cancelBubble!=null) evt.cancelBubble = true;
}

SERVLET JAVA CODE in doGet()
while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);            
};
outStream.close();
```

Comment: Side note: You appear to be using jQuery, which makes your `cancelBubble` function completely unnecessary. The event object jQuery gives you has `stopPropagation`, reliably, cross-browser.

Comment: Thanks.TH Crowder. I picked up the cancelBubble() snippet from a forum, that cautioned about stopPropagation() not being supported across all browsers.

Comment: Old IE doesn't have it, but jQuery handles that for you.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again

Comment: one suggestion would be to figure out if the issue is due to javascript/ajax request or if it the browsers handling of the response.  One way to do that would be to put a normal url in a (a href tag) and see if that works. If that doesn't work debugging it will be easier - it could be an issue with a response header (conent-type etc).  If that works then it is a javascript / ajax issue

Comment: Thanks gkamal. The normal request  (a href tag in js code, to download a pdf file from a different web site) from the Android Chrome  browser works fine. So must be a js/ajax issue. But it works fine other browsers, so question is what is the different handling that A-Chrome does, as compared to A-Opera / Firefox? In that, why it fails on first attempt.

Comment: Then it is most likely something related to the response headers or the first request is returning 303 response.  One way to debug these issues is to capture the http request / response either at the server side or client side. Either use a proxy tool like tcpmon (https://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html)  that intercepts and logs request / response headers or use a the developer console in the browser (not sure if it is supported on android)

Comment: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/12694 - take a look at this as well.  Might be relevant if you have setup ssl/https with self signed certificate

Comment: Thanks. Will checkout and revert. Must add here that  on first Get request file download begins with correct file name displayed, but then fails. So looks like header info is fine but maybe actual data xfer has a problem...